# Do sub-type objects going into a data structure become that data structure's declared type?

Tags: generics, kotlin, data-structures

Do sub-type objects going into a data structure become that data structure's declared type? For example, if I put dog objects into a list of mammals, does the objects' type change?

```
open class Mammal(str: String)

class Dog : Mammal("")

val d : Dog = Dog()

var listOfMammal: MutableList<Mammal> = mutableListOf()
listOfMammal.add(d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between static types and runtime types. The answer for both is "no", but for different reasons.

1. Static type is the type the compiler sees. Here `: Dog` and `: MutableList<Mammal>` specify static types (but `Dog()` doesn't). It isn't objects which have static types, but expressions. The type of `d` certainly doesn't change from calling `listOfMammal.add(d)`, you can still use it below and it's still `Dog`.

   And if you get a value `val e = listOfMammals[0]`, it has a different type but that's not changing the type of `d`, even though you know both `d` and `e` will point to the same object.
2. The runtime type is the class which an object has at runtime. It can't change on JVM; when a new object is created, its class is fixed.

Every static type can be erased to a runtime type (e.g `MutableList<Mammal>` is erased to `java.util.List`); and for any expression, if it evaluates to some value (object or primitive), the runtime type of that value will be a subtype of the erasure of the static type of the expression.

Comment: Well explained.  Also re. 2) due to type erasure, at runtime there's no such thing as a generic type (excepting reified types, which don't apply here).  So the JVM only sees a `MutableList`; it has no idea whether it's supposed to contain `Mammal`s or `Object`s or whatever.  So there's nothing that *could* change there.

Comment: To be more precise, JVM sees `ArrayList` (most likely), not `MutableList`. And of course the distinction between Kotlin `List` and `MutableList` also doesn't exist on JVM.